# Why windows service not start automatic after windows start

Tags: c#, windows-services

Why windows service not start automatic after windows start.

I set service installer property start type to automatic.

Is there other property which need to be set?

Logon for service is local system account. And service can be started manually every time.

Comment: No this should be enough. You should check in `services.msc` if the startup type has correctly been set to 'automatic' by the installer

Comment: Show the code of the service. There is a property to be set that makes Windows Service to start automatically.

Comment: are you sure that the service don't start? maybe it starts and then stops for some exception

Comment: Does the service have any dependencies?

Comment: maybe it starts before some other service which it needs

Comment: Check the windows event log which should tell you what happened with regard to the service starting.

Answer (score 2):

This happens most often when a resource needed by your service is not available when Windows tries to start it. Please review what your service needs to operate and ensure that you setup a dependency for each resource required. For example, if your service uses the network, try making it dependent on the "Workstation" service (named "LanmanWorkstation").

If you are in the post-Vista world, you can also set the startup type to "Automatic Delayed" to have Windows delay the starting of your service by about a minute. This is usually enough time for all the important/core services to establish themselves.

Comment: This answer somehow helped me. My service was dependent on MSSQLSERVER service. Starting it with a little delay solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Check in windows services settings. Maybe you didn't reinstall service after changing start type?

Comment: I did it, this is not a problem.